# $ \sum \limits_{k=n+2}^{2n+7} \frac{1}{k}$ Check if there is a limit to that sum. Is my solution correct?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I needed to check if a given sequence has a limit (there is no need to find that limit)

$$ \sum \limits_{k=n+2}^{2n+7} \frac{1}{k}$$

I saw that it is impossible to evaluate the limit using Stolz lemma (since I don't have any sequence in the denominator. So I did the test of value-change in $\infty$ (I don't know how it's called, I am sorry):

- $a_{n-1} = \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{n+3} + \frac{1}{n+4} + ... + \frac{1}{2n+6}$
- $a_{n} = \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{n+3} + \frac{1}{n+4} + ... + \frac{1}{2n+7}$

I kewn that in nominators I have arithmetic sequences that are always $\geq0$ and growing.

So I got:

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}} = \frac{\frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{n+3} + \frac{1}{n+4} + ... + \frac{1}{2n+7}}{\frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{n+3} + \frac{1}{n+4} + ... + \frac{1}{2n+6}} \implies \frac{0}{0}$$

And now I could use Stolz lemma:
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}} = \frac{\frac{1}{2n+7}}{\frac{1}{2n+5}} = \frac{2}{2}=1$$

The idea standing by that solution was that if in $\infty$ the difference between 2 elements is equal to $0$, then the sequence limited (because 'new' elements are equal).

However, my friend told me that this solution is wrong because there are plenty of seqences with $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}} = 0$ that are growing and are not limited. One of thouse would be $a_n = n$. So now I don't know if my solution is valid. I am actually worried that it's not.

But if it was wrong, then that test of $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}} $ would be totally useless in limit calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the theorem: **every monotone bounded sequence converges.**

First, this sequence is bounded: $$0<a_n=\sum_{k=n+2}^{2n+7}{\frac{1}{k}}<\frac{n+6}{n+2}=1+\frac{4}{n+2}<3.$$
Besides, it is decreasing:
\begin{align*}
a_{n+1}-a_n=\sum_{k=n+3}^{2n+9}{\frac{1}{k}}-\sum_{k=n+2}^{2n+7}{\frac{1}{k}}&=\frac{1}{2n+8}+\frac{1}{2n+9}-\frac{1}{n+2} \\
&=\left(\frac{1}{2n+8}-\frac{1}{2n+4}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2n+9}-\frac{1}{2n+4}\right)<0. 
\end{align*}
Then it must converge to some limit.

Comment: Yeah, but can I use the argument of $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}} = 1$? Is that also a correct way to prove that the sequence is bounded?

Comment: @theboyboy No, as your friend mentioned, it is a necessary condition for a convergent sequence but not sufficient. That is, we can find a sequence such as $a_n=n$ that satisfies this limit condition but diverges.

Comment: And could you explain to me how did you know that $ \sum \limits_{k=n+2}^{2n+7} \frac{1}{k} < \frac{n+6}{n+2}$? Why did you choose exactly $n+6$?

Comment: There are $n+6=(2n+7)-(n+1)$ summands and each summand is dominated by $1/(n+2)$.

Comment: So ultimately, my argument is totally useless in sense of proving limits or are there any use cases that you can think of?

Comment: Indeed, a sequence that satisfies this limit condition may fail to converge, but it must diverge if the limit $a_n/a_{n-1}$ not equals to $1$. This argument, at least, can help you determine whether a sequence *diverges* first.

Comment: Yeah, I think I understand now. If in the exercise, it was deeded to prove that the sequence has no limit I could then use $\frac{a_n}{a{a_{a-1}} != 1$, am I right now?

Comment: @theboyboy Perfectly correct!

Comment: Great, thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate the limit (more than is asked):
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=n+2}^{2n+7}\frac{1}{k}
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_n^{2n}\frac{dx}{x} = \ln 2 .
$$